# Xml parsing in iOS tutorial

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection, nsxmlparser

Hi i'm creating an app which have to print a value in label from an xml file in server.I tried reading some of documentation under google search..but i can't find it...Does any one know simple tutorial or any sample code that is used to integrate xml parsing in my app.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008094. Hope this example code will help you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use TBXml parser..That is the easiest way and also less time taken to parse a value..U can download TBXMLDemo project on [github](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML) and to print that instead of label u can use table view cell and make it selection as null.So that it looks simillarly like label.If u need more details comment me,..i'll be helping it..

Answer (score 20):

You can parse `XML` with below code. But you must need to create classes which you can find below.

```
    NSURL *URL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http:/sites.google.com/site/iphonesdktutorials/xml/Books.xml"];
    NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"string: %@", xmlString);
    NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:xmlString];
    NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", xmlDoc);
```

You need to create this classes for `XML` parsing with name of `XMLParser`.

**XMLParser.h**

```
//
//  XMLParser.h
//
//
//  Copyright 2016 Darshan kunjadiya. All rights reserved.


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-missing-property-synthesis"


typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, XMLDictionaryAttributesMode)
{
    XMLDictionaryAttributesModePrefixed = 0, //default
    XMLDictionaryAttributesModeDictionary,
    XMLDictionaryAttributesModeUnprefixed,
    XMLDictionaryAttributesModeDiscard
};


typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, XMLDictionaryNodeNameMode)
{
    XMLDictionaryNodeNameModeRootOnly = 0, //default
    XMLDictionaryNodeNameModeAlways,
    XMLDictionaryNodeNameModeNever
};


static NSString *const XMLDictionaryAttributesKey   = @"__attributes";
static NSString *const XMLDictionaryCommentsKey     = @"__comments";
static NSString *const XMLDictionaryTextKey         = @"__text";
static NSString *const XMLDictionaryNodeNameKey     = @"__name";
static NSString *const XMLDictionaryAttributePrefix = @"_";


@interface XMLURLParser : NSObject <NSCopying>

+ (XMLURLParser *)sharedInstance;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL collapseTextNodes; // defaults to YES
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL stripEmptyNodes;   // defaults to YES
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL trimWhiteSpace;    // defaults to YES
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL alwaysUseArrays;   // defaults to NO
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL preserveComments;  // defaults to NO
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL wrapRootNode;      // defaults to NO

@property (nonatomic, assign) XMLDictionaryAttributesMode attributesMode;
@property (nonatomic, assign) XMLDictionaryNodeNameMode nodeNameMode;

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithParser:(NSXMLParser *)parser;
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithData:(NSData *)data;
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithString:(NSString *)string;
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithFile:(NSString *)path;

@end


@interface NSDictionary (XMLParser)

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLParser:(NSXMLParser *)parser;
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLData:(NSData *)data;
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLString:(NSString *)string;
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLFile:(NSString *)path;

- (NSDictionary *)attributes;
- (NSDictionary *)childNodes;
- (NSArray *)comments;
- (NSString *)nodeName;
- (NSString *)innerText;
- (NSString *)innerXML;
- (NSString *)XMLString;

- (NSArray *)arrayValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath;
- (NSString *)stringValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath;
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath;

@end


@interface NSString (XMLParser)

- (NSString *)XMLEncodedString;

@end


#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

**XMLParser.m**

```
//
//  XMLParser.m
//
//
//  Copyright 2016 Darshan kunjadiya. All rights reserved.


#import "XMLParser.h"


#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-missing-property-synthesis"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdirect-ivar-access"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-non-iso"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wgnu"


#import <Availability.h>
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
#error This class requires automatic reference counting
#endif


@interface XMLURLParser () <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *root;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *stack;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *text;

@end


@implementation XMLURLParser

+ (XMLURLParser *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static XMLURLParser *sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{

        sharedInstance = [[XMLURLParser alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        _collapseTextNodes = YES;
        _stripEmptyNodes = YES;
        _trimWhiteSpace = YES;
        _alwaysUseArrays = NO;
        _preserveComments = NO;
        _wrapRootNode = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    XMLURLParser *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
    copy.collapseTextNodes = _collapseTextNodes;
    copy.stripEmptyNodes = _stripEmptyNodes;
    copy.trimWhiteSpace = _trimWhiteSpace;
    copy.alwaysUseArrays = _alwaysUseArrays;
    copy.preserveComments = _preserveComments;
    copy.attributesMode = _attributesMode;
    copy.nodeNameMode = _nodeNameMode;
    copy.wrapRootNode = _wrapRootNode;
    return copy;
}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithParser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
    id result = _root;
    _root = nil;
    _stack = nil;
    _text = nil;
    return result;
}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    return [self dictionaryWithParser:parser];
}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return [self dictionaryWithData:data];
}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithFile:(NSString *)path
{   
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return [self dictionaryWithData:data];
}

+ (NSString *)XMLStringForNode:(id)node withNodeName:(NSString *)nodeName
{   
    if ([node isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSMutableArray *nodes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[node count]];
        for (id individualNode in node)
        {
            [nodes addObject:[self XMLStringForNode:individualNode withNodeName:nodeName]];
        }
        return [nodes componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
    }
    else if ([node isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *attributes = [(NSDictionary *)node attributes];
        NSMutableString *attributeString = [NSMutableString string];
        for (NSString *key in [attributes allKeys])
        {
            [attributeString appendFormat:@" %@=\"%@\"", [[key description] XMLEncodedString], [[attributes[key] description] XMLEncodedString]];
        }

        NSString *innerXML = [node innerXML];
        if ([innerXML length])
        {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%1$@%2$@>%3$@</%1$@>", nodeName, attributeString, innerXML];
        }
        else
        {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@%@/>", nodeName, attributeString];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%1$@>%2$@</%1$@>", nodeName, [[node description] XMLEncodedString]];
    }
}

- (void)endText
{
    if (_trimWhiteSpace)
    {
        _text = [[_text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] mutableCopy];
    }
    if ([_text length])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *top = [_stack lastObject];
        id existing = top[XMLDictionaryTextKey];
        if ([existing isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            [existing addObject:_text];
        }
        else if (existing)
        {
            top[XMLDictionaryTextKey] = [@[existing, _text] mutableCopy];
        }
        else
        {
            top[XMLDictionaryTextKey] = _text;
        }
    }
    _text = nil;
}

- (void)addText:(NSString *)text
{   
    if (!_text)
    {
        _text = [NSMutableString stringWithString:text];
    }
    else
    {
        [_text appendString:text];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(__unused NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(__unused NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{   
    [self endText];

    NSMutableDictionary *node = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    switch (_nodeNameMode)
    {
        case XMLDictionaryNodeNameModeRootOnly:
        {
            if (!_root)
            {
                node[XMLDictionaryNodeNameKey] = elementName;
            }
            break;
        }
        case XMLDictionaryNodeNameModeAlways:
        {
            node[XMLDictionaryNodeNameKey] = elementName;
            break;
        }
        case XMLDictionaryNodeNameModeNever:
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if ([attributeDict count])
    {
        switch (_attributesMode)
        {
            case XMLDictionaryAttributesModePrefixed:
            {
                for (NSString *key in [attributeDict allKeys])
                {
                    node[[XMLDictionaryAttributePrefix stringByAppendingString:key]] = attributeDict[key];
                }
                break;
            }
            case XMLDictionaryAttributesModeDictionary:
            {
                node[XMLDictionaryAttributesKey] = attributeDict;
                break;
            }
            case XMLDictionaryAttributesModeUnprefixed:
            {
                [node addEntriesFromDictionary:attributeDict];
                break;
            }
            case XMLDictionaryAttributesModeDiscard:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!_root)
    {
        _root = node;
        _stack = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:node];
        if (_wrapRootNode)
        {
            _root = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:_root forKey:elementName];
            [_stack insertObject:_root atIndex:0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *top = [_stack lastObject];
        id existing = top[elementName];
        if ([existing isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            [existing addObject:node];
        }
        else if (existing)
        {
            top[elementName] = [@[existing, node] mutableCopy];
        }
        else if (_alwaysUseArrays)
        {
            top[elementName] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:node];
        }
        else
        {
            top[elementName] = node;
        }
        [_stack addObject:node];
    }
}

- (NSString *)nameForNode:(NSDictionary *)node inDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    if (node.nodeName)
    {
        return node.nodeName;
    }
    else
    {
        for (NSString *name in dict)
        {
            id object = dict[name];
            if (object == node)
            {
                return name;
            }
            else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [object containsObject:node])
            {
                return name;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(__unused NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(__unused NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(__unused NSString *)qName
{   
    [self endText];

    NSMutableDictionary *top = [_stack lastObject];
    [_stack removeLastObject];

    if (!top.attributes && !top.childNodes && !top.comments)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *newTop = [_stack lastObject];
        NSString *nodeName = [self nameForNode:top inDictionary:newTop];
        if (nodeName)
        {
            id parentNode = newTop[nodeName];
            if (top.innerText && _collapseTextNodes)
            {
                if ([parentNode isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
                {
                    parentNode[[parentNode count] - 1] = top.innerText;
                }
                else
                {
                    newTop[nodeName] = top.innerText;
                }
            }
            else if (!top.innerText && _stripEmptyNodes)
            {
                if ([parentNode isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
                {
                    [parentNode removeLastObject];
                }
                else
                {
                    [newTop removeObjectForKey:nodeName];
                }
            }
            else if (!top.innerText && !_collapseTextNodes && !_stripEmptyNodes)
            {
                top[XMLDictionaryTextKey] = @"";
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [self addText:string];
}

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    [self addText:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser foundComment:(NSString *)comment
{
    if (_preserveComments)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *top = [_stack lastObject];
        NSMutableArray *comments = top[XMLDictionaryCommentsKey];
        if (!comments)
        {
            comments = [@[comment] mutableCopy];
            top[XMLDictionaryCommentsKey] = comments;
        }
        else
        {
            [comments addObject:comment];
        }
    }
}

@end


@implementation NSDictionary(XMLDictionary)

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLParser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    return [[[XMLURLParser sharedInstance] copy] dictionaryWithParser:parser];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLData:(NSData *)data
{
    return [[[XMLURLParser sharedInstance] copy] dictionaryWithData:data];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLString:(NSString *)string
{
    return [[[XMLURLParser sharedInstance] copy] dictionaryWithString:string];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLFile:(NSString *)path
{
    return [[[XMLURLParser sharedInstance] copy] dictionaryWithFile:path];
}

- (NSDictionary *)attributes
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = self[XMLDictionaryAttributesKey];
    if (attributes)
    {
        return [attributes count]? attributes: nil;
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *filteredDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self];
        [filteredDict removeObjectsForKeys:@[XMLDictionaryCommentsKey, XMLDictionaryTextKey, XMLDictionaryNodeNameKey]];
        for (NSString *key in [filteredDict allKeys])
        {
            [filteredDict removeObjectForKey:key];
            if ([key hasPrefix:XMLDictionaryAttributePrefix])
            {
                filteredDict[[key substringFromIndex:[XMLDictionaryAttributePrefix length]]] = self[key];
            }
        }
        return [filteredDict count]? filteredDict: nil;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSDictionary *)childNodes
{   
    NSMutableDictionary *filteredDict = [self mutableCopy];
    [filteredDict removeObjectsForKeys:@[XMLDictionaryAttributesKey, XMLDictionaryCommentsKey, XMLDictionaryTextKey, XMLDictionaryNodeNameKey]];
    for (NSString *key in [filteredDict allKeys])
    {
        if ([key hasPrefix:XMLDictionaryAttributePrefix])
        {
            [filteredDict removeObjectForKey:key];
        }
    }
    return [filteredDict count]? filteredDict: nil;
}

- (NSArray *)comments
{
    return self[XMLDictionaryCommentsKey];
}

- (NSString *)nodeName
{
    return self[XMLDictionaryNodeNameKey];
}

- (id)innerText
{   
    id text = self[XMLDictionaryTextKey];
    if ([text isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        return [text componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
    }
    else
    {
        return text;
    }
}

- (NSString *)innerXML
{   
    NSMutableArray *nodes = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *comment in [self comments])
    {
        [nodes addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!--%@-->", [comment XMLEncodedString]]];
    }

    NSDictionary *childNodes = [self childNodes];
    for (NSString *key in childNodes)
    {
        [nodes addObject:[XMLURLParser XMLStringForNode:childNodes[key] withNodeName:key]];
    }

    NSString *text = [self innerText];
    if (text)
    {
        [nodes addObject:[text XMLEncodedString]];
    }

    return [nodes componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
}

- (NSString *)XMLString
{
    if ([self count] == 1 && ![self nodeName])
    {
        //ignore outermost dictionary
        return [self innerXML];
    }
    else
    {
        return [XMLURLParser XMLStringForNode:self withNodeName:[self nodeName] ?: @"root"];
    }
}

- (NSArray *)arrayValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    id value = [self valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
    if (value && ![value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        return @[value];
    }
    return value;
}

- (NSString *)stringValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    id value = [self valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        value = [value count]? value[0]: nil;
    }
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        return [(NSDictionary *)value innerText];
    }
    return value;
}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    id value = [self valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        value = [value count]? value[0]: nil;
    }
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        return @{XMLDictionaryTextKey: value};
    }
    return value;
}

@end


@implementation NSString (XMLDictionary)

- (NSString *)XMLEncodedString
{   
    return [[[[[self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"]
               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"&lt;"]
              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"&gt;"]
             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"&quot;"]
            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\'" withString:@"&apos;"];
}

@end
```

i hope this answer is useful for you.

Comment: This creates issue when there is array of dictionary :|

Comment: This creates lots of issue for ARC based coding!! Fix it!

Comment: @JayprakashDubey okay i will check and update this answer.

Comment: change a little code for ARC and it works like charm. Thanks

Comment: This class needs up-gradation for earlier versions of iOS..

Comment: 1 Thank you so much I am a new in xml parser its working superb nice thanks a lot.    Guys If you want sample url try this  :: NSString *url=@"http:/sites.google.com/site/iphonesdktutorials/xml/Books.xml";

Comment: @NSPratik  Now XMLParser classes is upgraded. See the edited answer. Thanks