# How to use XMLReader

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, sigabrt

I am trying to make an app in objective-c that will parse an xml document like so using XMLReader (https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader):

```
    <episodes>
  <title>title title title</title>
  <link>link link link</link>
  <description>description description description</description>
  <item>
    <title>title title title</title>
    <link>link link link</link>
    <description>description description description</description>
  </item>
  <item>
...
</episodes>
```

I honestly have no idea how I'm supposed to do this. I have already imported the two files included in the zip, but when I try to call

```
NSData *data = http://link.to.xml/file // some data that can be received from remote service
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data 
                                             options:XMLReaderOptionsProcessNamespaces 
                                               error:&error];
```

it crashes giving me a SIGABRT on main thread. Can anyone help with this??? Also, how do I get the resulting NSArray or NSDictionary into a table view?

Answer (score 1):

Check the post by Troy http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/

Also, There are plenty of examples out there which can get you started. Check out the answers here for a similar question: [Xml parsing in iOS tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323326/xml-parsing-in-ios-tutorial.Its) always good idea to code through some tutorials before actual implementation.

Comment: Do you recommend any one of those? Which one would you use?

Comment: check the first link by Troy Brant. XMLReader was originated from his project so his example will clear your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just write:

```
NSData *data = http://link.to.xml/file // some data that can be received from remote service
```

To get data from a URL. At least use something like NSData's `+dataWithContentsOfURL:`, except that it going to be synchronous and not very user friendly.

I don't think your problem is the data parsing at this point; you're having trouble getting the data which is a whole subject in itself, apart from parsing XML. You could start with the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) which will show you how to get data properly.

Comment: oops, thats not actually what I had, it was NSData *data = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://link.to.xml/file"]

Comment: That won't work either, that creates an NSURL object not an NSData object.

Comment: So how could I make an NSData object out of an NSURL?

Comment: `NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"link_to_xml_file"]];` As I tried to hint at in the answer.