# How to parse XML from web services into NSArray in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsdictionary, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse this xml to my application, but my NSDictionary is always nil when I debug

This xml

```
<DADOS_MESA>
    <MESA>
        <Id>1076</Id>
        <Date>2015-05-08T09:44:25.343</Date>
    </MESA>
<DADOS_MESA>
```

I am requesting this XML from my WS, with

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myIP/Services.asmx/GetDetails?CId=02&SId=01"]];
```

Then I create an NSDictionary

```
NSDictionary *xml = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

The NSDictionary always come nil(I don't know why), Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend this library, iOS doesn't support XML this way by default: https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/index.html) to do this. Here is a sample code.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myIP/Services.asmx/GetDetails?CId=02&SId=01"]];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser didStartElement:(NSString*)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString*)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString*)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary*)attributeDict
{
    //Use attributeDict to get parsed XML into NSDictionary
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:
 [NSXMLParser](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)  & [Darshan Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323326/xml-parsing-in-ios-tutorial)