# Not getting data from web service

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

While trying to print data using `po data` it says

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'data'
>   error: 1 errors parsing expression

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSMutableURLRequest*req=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/"];
    [req setURL:url];
    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession]dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"error");
        }else{}
    }] resume];
}
```

Comment: Actually the data is returned within the  pair of braces `{}` after `else`. If you don't use it at all, you can't see anything. Consider also that `URLSession` works asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting error below in console?

```
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
```

I feel you have to configure App Transport Security Exception for "http:" url.

Please look in to the below question to understand adding exception.

[Transport security blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

**Update :**

The above url gives xml response, refer to below link for xml parsing

[xml parsing in ios tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323326/xml-parsing-in-ios-tutorial)

Comment: no...not that.. i added in plist. not getting data and response  using po it says using "po data" it says error: use of undeclared identifier 'data' error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: I tried the above code, and got a XML response. Please parse the xml file using NSXMLParser.

Comment: @Nishanth Still getting blank data?

Comment: Great it helped you. Please mark this as answer, if it resolved your issue. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set a breakpoint in the "else" branch.When the data comes back,then it will trigger breakpoint in it, use the "po data".