# SOAP response stored into NSString need to be parsed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, soap

I have this SOAP Request and my response has been stored into a NSString, I need to read this response and get data stored into a field. This is an example of my response:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><ReadDataResponse xmlns="http://sysman.it/webservices/"><ReadDataResult>success</ReadDataResult><Data><TableName>V_CP_NOTIFICATIONS_DEVICEID</TableName><values><ArrayOfCpFieldAndValue><cpFieldAndValue><Name /><Value>0</Value><Type>IntegerType</Type><CompOperator>=</CompOperator></cpFieldAndValue></ArrayOfCpFieldAndValue></values><keys><cpFieldAndValue><Name>DEVICE_ID</Name><Value>1006be49b73a98af</Value><Type>VarcharType</Type><CompOperator>=</CompOperator></cpFieldAndValue><cpFieldAndValue><Name>PUSH_READCNT</Name><Value>0</Value><Type>IntegerType</Type><CompOperator>=</CompOperator></cpFieldAndValue></keys><orClause>false</orClause></Data></ReadDataResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

`<cpFieldAndValue><Name /><Value>0</Value>` I need that number to be stored into a variable. This is my code at the moment:

```
NSData *postData = [sSOAPMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"----"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Request reply: %@", requestReply);

}] resume];
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you look at any XML parser? Like `NSXMLParser`?

Comment: @Larme my xml is stored as NSString

Comment: That's not answering the question. Your response is XML. So you need to parse XML. So did you look how to parse XML in Objective-C?

Comment: @Larme yes of course, and I can't get it work

Comment: And what are your attempts then? I'm not familiar with XML parsing, but if someone whom is and sees your question, he/she might spot your error, but might be lazy in parsing the whole XML for you. Also your question seems to be "code for me".

Comment: @ChefTraian Please check my answer and let me know if you have any confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can refer to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161072/5807290). You have to copy the [XMLParser.h](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzkfckggditaupa/XMLParser.m?dl=0) and [XMLParser.m](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2xk0jin3f6l2veb/XMLParser.h?dl=0) files and use as follows:

```
NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:xmlString];
NSInteger value = [[xmlDoc valueForKeyPath:@"soap:Body.ReadDataResponse.Data.values.ArrayOfCpFieldAndValue.cpFieldAndValue.Value"] integerValue];
NSLog(@"%d", value);
```

**Output:**

```
0
```

Comment: Thank that solved my problem, now I just need an hint I'm storing this data into a session. NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) { ... How can I use this variable outside the session?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer You can do two things one is call this function which returns this block for that you can refer to https://medium.com/@amyjoscelyn/blocks-and-closures-in-objective-c-2b763e9e0dc8

Comment: Or you can use NSURLSessionDelegate https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiondelegate?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

You have to use NSXMLParser

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxmlparser

Please find some example code explains below

https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/parsing-xml-tutorial